# Pandas 2.0 の melt メソッドでタイムゾーンが変わってしまう

Tags: python, python3, pandas

新しい Pandas で `melt` を使用すると、日付のタイムゾーンが変わりました。
不具合でしょうか。

```
!pip3 install pandas
!pip3 list | grep pandas

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    {'type': 'A0', 'start_date': pd.Timestamp('2023/03/01', tz='Asia/Tokyo'), 'end_date': pd.Timestamp('2023/03/10', tz='Asia/Tokyo')},
    {'type': 'A1', 'start_date': pd.Timestamp('2023/03/01', tz='Asia/Tokyo'), 'end_date': pd.Timestamp('2023/03/11', tz='Asia/Tokyo')},
], index=['aaaa', 'bbbb'])
display(df)

df = df.melt(id_vars=['type'], value_vars=['start_date', 'end_date'], var_name='start/end', value_name='date')
display(df)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

当問題（Pandasのmeltメソッドは、Timestamp型のタイムゾーンを引き継がない問題）のIssueを起票しました。
あれからしばらくたち、最近リリースされたPandas2.1.4を確認したところ、修正されていないようです。
なぜ反映/修正されないのか、分かる方教えていただけないでしょうか？
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/55254

Comment: リンク先を辿っていくと、v2.2.0でのリリースに取り込まれるように見えます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。v2.2.0のリリースを待ちます。リンクをたどっていけるよう、読み直します。*.rstファイルを見ればよさそうなこと分かりました。

Answer (score 3):

問題の箇所は以下です。

[melt() in melt.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/reshape/melt.py#L143)

```py
if frame.shape[1] > 0:
    mdata[value_name] = concat(
        [frame.iloc[:, i] for i in range(frame.shape[1])]
    ).values
else:
                    :
```

この部分を質問のソースコードに当てはめると以下の様になります。(原因は `values`)

```py
from pandas.core.reshape.concat import concat

frame = df[['start_date', 'end_date']]
print(concat(
          [frame.iloc[:, i] for i in range(frame.shape[1])]
      ).values)

# ['2023-02-28T15:00:00.000000000' '2023-02-28T15:00:00.000000000'
#  '2023-03-09T15:00:00.000000000' '2023-03-10T15:00:00.000000000']
```

ちなみに、`melt()` の実行後に timezone を再設定する方法は以下です。

```py
df = df.melt(id_vars=['type'], value_vars=['start_date', 'end_date'], var_name='start/end', value_name='date')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], utc=True).dt.tz_convert(tz='Asia/Tokyo')
print(df)

#   type   start/end                      date
# 0   A0  start_date 2023-03-01 00:00:00+09:00
# 1   A1  start_date 2023-03-01 00:00:00+09:00
# 2   A0    end_date 2023-03-10 00:00:00+09:00
# 3   A1    end_date 2023-03-11 00:00:00+09:00
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。timezoneを再設定することで、回避（仮対応）できました。